# Unable to Add user with @ symbol

Tags: wso2-identity-server

While adding a user in WSO2 Identity Server (Eg. sreedhar@xyz.com) following error is thrown.

Could not add user PRIMARY/sreedhar@xyz.com. Error is: Username sreedhar@xyz.com is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format

I changed the regular expression too as below

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@+[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

It is working in a simple java application.

Help appreciated, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the user-mgt.xml file as follows to add email usernames,

```
<Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property> 
<Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
```

You can user complex regular expressions as well.

Thanks
Isura